# How do you classify languages into regular, context free, and phrase-structure?

Tags: context-free-grammar, language-theory, regular-language

If you're given a language, how do you figure out if it's regular, CF but not regular, or phrase-structure but not CF? Is there a good way to attack this problem? I could randomly try to make FAs or PDAs, but I feel like there's a better way to do it.

Classic example:

L = { a^n b^n c^n | n >= 0 }

Where would one start?
Thanks.

Comment: is this your homework?  You should use the "homework" tag if it is, though this question seems to be asking for general guidance on homework, which seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You sort of get a feel for classifying them.  I don't know of a very methodical approach.  Since languages are usually subsets and supersets of each other, you estimate where it fits in that hierarchy and show that it can't be, say, a regular language, but it could be a CFL.